# PHP/SQL statement outputs error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am still working on a website with a movie database. The problem I have, is that my SQL statement for deleting a movie from the database isn't executed. I have got two pages, one page where the user can see the movies, and one with the code that is executed when one clicks on the delete button.

Following is the code for the information of one of the movies from the overview, since the code for other movies are about the same:

```
    <div><tr><td><div style="width: 200px; height:296px; margin-top: 50px">
    <div class="image-hover">
    <img src="img/deadpool.jpg" width="200px" height="296px"/>
    <span class="desc"><div class="filmtitle"><?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT title FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1a);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["title"] ;}}?></div>
   <div style="font-size:8px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#000;">
    <div class="black"><div class="filmdiscription"><b>Samenvatting: </b> <?
    php
    $sql1b = "SELECT description FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1b);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row["description"];}
    }

    ?>
    <div style="font-size:8px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#000;">
    <div class="black2"><div class="yearrating"><b>Jaar: </b> <?php
    $sql1c = "SELECT release_year FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1c);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row["release_year"];}
    }?>
    <div style="font-size:8px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#000;">
    <div class="black2"><div class="yearrating" ><b>Rating (0-5): </b> <?php
    $sql1d = "SELECT rating FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1d);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row["rating"];}
    }?>
    </div>
    <div class="black2"><div class="yearrating">
    <a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id='.$row['film_id'].'" ></i> 
    Delete <?php '</a>'?> <center>
        </span>
    </div></div>
    </div></div>
```

The code for 'deletemovie.php':

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<?php
session_start(); //De sessie wordt gestart.
function is_logged() {
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) return true;
return false; //Er wordt gekeken of de gebruikersnaam correct is.
}
if(!is_logged()){
header("Location: sign-in.php"); //Als de gebruiker naar overzichtlogin.php 
gaat, zonder dat hij of zij is ingelogd, worden ze doorgestuurd naar de 
login pagina.
}

require_once('db_const.php'); //De gegevens voor de database verbinding 
worden in 1 centraal bestand opgehaald.
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if  (!$mysqli){
die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()); //Als de verbinding niet 
lukt zal deze niet werken.
}

?>

<?php $current = 'delete'; ?> <!-- Om aan te geven dat men zich op de 
beveiligde overzichtspagina bevindt, wordt gebruik gemaakt van deze 
variabele. Current krijgt nu de waarde 'secured', waardoor de button waar 
'secured' staat een kleur krijgt. -->

<body>

<div class="header">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
require_once("headersecured.php"); //Indien de gebruiker ingelogd is, wordt 
'headersecured.php' gebruikt als header.
}else{
require_once("header.php"); //Indien de gebruiker niet is ingelogd, wordt 
header.php gebruikt als header.
}
?>
</div>

 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);


$id = $_GET["id"]; //Het ID van de film wordt opgehaald.

$sql = "DELETE FROM films WHERE film_id = $id"; //De film waarbij het ID 
hoort wordt verwijderd uit de database.

?>

<?php

   if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) { //Zorgt ervoor dat de film wordt 
verwijderd.
  echo "Succesvol verwijderd!"; //Laat zien dat de film verwijderd is uit de 
database.
  echo "<br>"; // Witruimte
  echo "<a href='overzichtlogin.php'>Terug naar de vorige pagina.</a>"; 
//Door op deze link te klikken gaat de gebruiker terug naar de 
overzichtspagina.
  } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli); //Indien het 
verwijderen niet goed is gegaan, wordt er een foutmelding getoond.
  }
?>


<div class="footer">
<?php include 'footer.php';?> <!-- de footer wordt opgehaald -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When someone clicks 'Delete' in the overview, the movie is supposed to be deleted from the database. When clicked it gives an error:

> Error: DELETE FROM films WHERE film_id = '.$row['film_id'].'
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'film_id'].'' at line 1"

What should I change in my code?

Comment: FIrst of all parametrize query, It could be SQL Injected now.

Comment: `WHERE film_id = $id` is in your code.Where do you get `WHERE film_id = '.$row['film_id'].'` in your error message? Or you are not showing the real code?

Comment: @Mihai It is a part of the code I'm using.

Comment: Indent your code, it will make it MUCH, MUCH more readable. I don't think you knew, but the first html file, contains a span that gets closed by the opening of the following div, a unclosed center tag, a unopened `i` tag, the closing tag of aforementioned span, unclosed table row and -cell tags outside of a table. Also try to split PHP and HTML as much as possible. Finally, those comments in the second file, better translate them from dutch to english when posting it on StackOverflow

Comment: There's something you didn't do in the related SELECT. I'm surprised nobody noticed that, nor the answer given. Edit (ping): How about you @chris85 ? ;-)

Comment: `$sql = "DELETE FROM films WHERE film_id = $id";` did you check the query generate from this is correct?

Comment: @chris85 actually, the related column wasn't selected ;-) Oh.. I just gave it away!!

Comment: @chris85 you/they forgot to select the `film_id` column ;-)

Comment: @chris85 I know; all the more reasons why I didn't post an answer here. They'll have to go through comments and wait for another answer, or stick with the one already given, which doesn't seem to be further helping them so far and isn't responding to a comment I left under their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missing php open/closing tags. Try to change this row:

```
<a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id='.$row['film_id'].'" ></i>
```

To

```
<a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id=<?php echo $row['film_id']; ?>" ></i>
```

Or shorter way:

```
<a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id=<?= $row['film_id']; ?>" ></i>
```

And use parameters in query to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. the error is still there

Comment: you missed something in the related SELECT

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you where the issue starts, which is here:

```
<a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id='.$row['film_id'].'" ></i> 
    Delete <?php '</a>'?>
```

specifically at:

```
'.$row['film_id'].'
```

you are in a plain text document so PHP is not going to interact with it. You'd need to do:

```
<a class="alert" href="deletemovie.php?id=<?php echo $row['film_id']; ?>" ></i>
```

I also am not clear why you want PHP to generate the closing element there but you need an `echo` for PHP to output anything (or `print`).

```
    Delete <?php echo '</a>';?>
```

Once you are running that you will get an `undefined index` error because you never selected `film_id` in your `select`.

```
SELECT rating, film_id FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'
```

You also should use parameterized queries and consolidate your queries.

For the selection:

```
SELECT description, release_year, rating FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'
```

or

```
SELECT description, release_year, rating, film_id FROM films WHERE film_id = '1'
```

if you want to use the `film_id` index on the return, it seems like to me you'd already know this, or you shouldn't have the `where` clause.

Your delete should be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM films WHERE film_id = ?";
```

then bind `$id`.

Read more here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php